# How to write a code for fetch image file local machine directory in cucumber using watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, watir

I am new to automation please help me
Using paperclip in my application

feature/test_step.rb

```
When("Enter valid details for create user") do
  browser.a(xpath:"/html/body/a[2]").click
  text = browser.text_field id: 'hospital_name'
  text.exist?
  text.set'Jone'
  text = browser.text_field id: 'hospital_address'
  text.exist?
  text.set'chennai'
  text = browser.text_field id: 'hospital_email_id'
  text.exist?
  text.set'jonesdfsdf'
  text = browser.text_field id: 'hospital_phone_number'
  text.exist?
  text.set'sdfsdfsdf'
  sleep(2)
  browser.button(type: 'file').click
  sleep(10)
```

**How to fetch a image file in local directory code here**

```
  browser.file_field.set ("/home/hospital_Management/images.jpeg")

end
```

Comment: Write 'exist?' with if condition ! And your question is not clear, you want download file into your local drive? file_field actually loads the file.

Comment: How to fetch a image file from local directory using  cucumber rails watir

Comment: WATIR is only to operate on browser, but what you are asking here is window based operation.